# unable to set properties of editText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am defining an EditText array in a class outside any methods.

I want to use the first member of the EditText[] in the onCreate method. Will i have to define it again in the onCreate method to set the properties of the EditText.

```
EditText items[]=new EditText[30];
EditText rates[]=new EditText[30];
EditText quants[]=new EditText[30];

int no,id;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    items[0].setHint("Enter the item");
    items[0].setId(0);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've declared a new array, but you haven't added any objects to it. You need to do this:

```
items[0] = new EditText(this);
items[0].setHint("Enter the item");
items[0].setId(0);
```

This is assigning the value at `items` index `0` to a new `EditText` object, otherwise the value at `items[0]` would be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

First it has to be casted!!
Else you can't!.

Here You Go!!!

```
RelativeLayout relative_layout;
private TextView tv[] = new TextView[27];
tv[0] = (TextView) relative_layout.findViewById(R.id.tv1);

tv[i].setText("HELLO");
```

Comment: -1 The item he is trying to access is `null`, casting won't help

Comment: Hey, that should be the first step! after, EditText items[]=new EditText[30];

Comment: OK, if you think that will help please post some code with an explanation of why it will work.

Comment: The downvote was because what you posted really should have been a comment, rather than an answer because you provided no code nor explanation. Since you have now provided code and a sort-of explanation, I have removed the downvote.

Comment: I have added that as comment, since I don't have enough reputations to add comment!!